# Netbeans and entities generation

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans, foreign-keys

I have a problem generating entities with Netbeans, if a table has more than one relationship with another table.

I have, for example, a `Task` table with three references to `User` table: the `user` who created the `task`, the `user` who have to `track` the task and the `user` who is executing it. Every relationship has its name: `fk_user_created`, `fk_user_resp`, `fk_user_do`.

Netbeans generate three collections: `UserCollection1`, `UserCollection2` and `UserCollection3`. Not only the names are unclear but, when I regenerate the entities, they change order.

Is there a way to tell Netbeans to use the foreign key name instead of the table or column name?

I know I can directly write Entities instead of automatically generate them, but this is not the case, I'm testing solutions and different database structures and I keep track manually of every change is not practical.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Foreign Key is used by the `database`. It is how the DB knows which column from a given table references which other table's column.

When you automatically generate Entities in Netbeans, they use the Table and Column name because that is how it recognizes where the column is referencing.

There is no explicit way of telling Netbeans to use the foreign key names, unless you manually change it. Which I would not recommend as it may lead to compilation conflicts.